# Change language of standard contextMenu in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, translation

I try to change the language of the standard contextMenu of `QLineEdit`, and all other TextEdit components in `PyQt5`. The language is in english but my locale language is german.
So Cut, Copy, Paste,Undo, Redo and the other things should be in german.
i tried with:

```
translator = QTranslator()
translator.load('qt_' + QLocale.system().name(),QLibraryInfo.location(QLibraryInfo.TranslationsPath))
app.installTranslator(translator)
```

but that does'nt work. What i have to do.

This is my code:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

translator = QTranslator(app)
translator.load('qt_' + QLocale.system().name(), QLibraryInfo.location(QLibraryInfo.TranslationsPath)))
app.installTranslator(translator)

#print(translator.load('qt_' + QLocale.system().name(), QLibraryInfo.location(QLibraryInfo.TranslationsPath)))
#print(app.installTranslator(translator))

window = mainwindow()
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I dont know why but both prints give me `False`
But why?

If i do `print(translator.language())` it return me `de`, so i dont understand why the translation is not working.
any idea?

Comment: Do you run this before creating ui or after?
Check if path `QLibraryInfo.location(QLibraryInfo.TranslationsPath)` exists and contains translation files.

Comment: I run this after app = Qapplikation() the path exist and the qm_de file is in the folder

Comment: I design my UI in in qt-designer and the property "locale" is set to germany, german. I thought this set the language to germany but no.

Comment: I tried this with `qt_de` and it worked fine for me. Do `translator.load()` and `app.installTranslator()` both return `True`, and are you keeping a permanent reference to the translator object?

Comment: What do you mean with permanent reference? What I wrote above I write after app= Qapplikation () in the main function. I also tried with 'qt_de' but the menu is still in english

Comment: I have edit my question

Comment: @Robert That should only be because there's no translation file installed at the specified location, or that it somehow isn't readable. Try copying a known, valid translation filepath, and then load from that: e.g. `translator.load('qt_de.qm', '/usr/share/qt/translations')`. If that doesn't work, use `QFileInfo` to check that both the directory and file are readable.

Comment: yes, it works. The problem was the path i gave him. Thank you very much